# One-to-One and One-to-Many relation to the same model with same reverse accessor

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have an order model with a one to many relation to a OrderDate Model. Now I want have an additional field on order named 'chosen_date' with a one to one relation to the same OrderDate Model. The Problem is that my relations at OrderDate both have the name 'order', which clashes.  How can I solve this problem without adding a new field like 'Order_2' on the OrderDate Model?

Here are my models:

```
class Order(TimeStampedModel):
    chosen_date = models.OneToOneField('OrderDate', on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
```

```
class OrderDate(TimeStampedModel):
    order = models.ForeignKey(Order, related_name='dates', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    date = models.DateField()
    morning = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    noon = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    evening = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You specify the `related_name` for the `OneToOneField`:

```
class Order(TimeStampedModel):
    chosen_date = models.OneToOneField(
        'OrderDate',
        related_name='order_picked',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        blank=True,
        null=True
    )
```

Comment: yes that would work, but then I have one field 'order' and one field 'order_picked'. They will never both have a value. So I thought there maybe is another way to do it.

Comment: @lando: but the two are different. The `.order` simply means to what `Order` the `OrderDate` was *eligible*, not picked. So it makes no sense to "merge" the two, since `myorderdate.order` refers to the `Order` that *can* pick it, whereas `myorderdate.order_picked`, means your `Order` picked that one (and will raise an `AttributeError` if it was not picked).

Comment: thanks for the explanation, I just thought there is maybe are more elegant way. My other option would be to add a bool 'chosen' to the OrderDate model